# What is the ZAP range of an Ingress Portal

Tags: ingress

When you attack or hack an enemy portal in Ingress, the portal will ZAP you for XM damage. The amount of damage is dependent on the level of the portal, not the level of the resonators in there, and is documented.

I have been unable to find more information about portal ZAP range, or other attack properties, though.

What is the ZAP range of a portal?
Is there is limit to the firing rate or the firepower of a portal, or will it always ZAP you for any attack/hack?

Comment: But the level of the portal is calculated from the level of the resonators. So the level of the portal thus the damage it does is linked to the level of the resonators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The range within which a portal may counter attack appears to be twice of your hacking radius, i.e. around 70m. I have read of attacking high level portals standing just outside range to avoid XM depletion, esp. for high level farms.

Note that firing bursters from afar also means their damage is greatly reduced and you will need many more of them. However, since the actual firing of an XMP uses far less XM than the portal zap, this is a means to take down high level portals that would otherwise suck all XM from the scanner.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this question is now [almost] five years old, but I found it because I needed the same info, others may do likewise, so I believe it is worth adding that the latest version (0.1.4.20170430.123533) of the IITC ZapRange Plugin calculates a portal's zap range as:

`var range = (5*portalLevel)+35;`

Hence:

```
Portal Level         Zap Range
1                    40m
2                    45m
3                    50m
4                    55m
5                    60m
6                    65m
7                    70m
8                    85m
```

Comment: Looks like a typo in your asnwer, L8 zap range should be 75m not 85?

Answer (score 1):

Higher level portals have higher zap range.
Numbers I have seen are 35m + (portal level * 5m). So between 40m and 75m.
I do think these numbers have changed though. I think a level 8 portal zaps you at 80m now. At 90m you are safe anyhow.